# ASP.NET Core Web API doesn't run after publishing and giving 500.30 error after uploadig to the host

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, deployment

I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET Core Web API to a host (mochahost) but I get  some errors; after publishing the app from Visual Studio and trying to run the (.exe) file this was the result:

[image]

And after uploading the published files to my hosting account this error occurred:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the Resources folder wasn't sharing during the publish process
I solved the issue with this line in (.csproj) file:

```
<Content Include="Resources\**">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```